# Laravel array concatenate

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I need to make paramaters type array like this:

```
$arrayExemple= [
        ['value1', 'value2'],
        ['value1', 'value2'],
        ['value1', 'value2'],
        ['value1', 'value2']
    ];
```

In my cas i need to check

```
if($test == "test"){ $arrayExemple = //i need to set array there }
```

i need to know how to make this please !

Comment: It seems unclear what you are asking. Could you please add some detail and specify what your problem is? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to append `[]` to the variable name to add something to an array, without overwriting what is already inside.

```
if ($test == "test") {
    $arrayExample[] = [
        "value1",
        "value2"
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array with key/value like this :

```
$array = [
    "value1" => "value2",
    "value1" => "value2",
    "value1" => "value2",
    "value1" => "value2",
];
```